# Export report from SonarQube_6.7.6

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web, sonarqube6.3

I have installed Sonarqube 6.7.6 and sonar-scanner (sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-windows).
I have analyzed my code and the results are at dashboard.

Now, I need to export the report in XML or Excel or PDF format (Anything among these are fine).

I have googled and found some answers like,

> **To get an HTML report, set the sonar.issuesReport.html.enable property to true. To define its location, set the
>   sonar.issuesReport.html.location property to an absolute or relative
>   path to the destination folder for the HTML report. The default value
>   is .sonar/issues-report/ for the SonarQube Runner and Ant, and
>   target/sonar/issues-report/ for Maven. By default 2 html reports are
>   generated: The full report (default name is issues-report.html) The
>   light report (default name is issues-report-light.html) that will only
>   contains new issues.**

But I have included these in my project property file, yet the report is not found.

Can anyone please help me out of this ?

Comment: Isn't this a separate plugin? Have you installed the plugin?

Comment: Yes i have installed a separate plugin plugin PDF plugin and issue report plugin and its not working as per the procedure. how to implement that? 
Do we have a inbuilt plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get the HTML Report plugin to work, either. I found another way to create a report using the [SonarQube Web API](https://codeen-app.euclid-ec.org/sonar/web_api/api/issues) to extract data in JSON format, which can then be converted to a csv file using Java and a JSON Conversion library (I use [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson)).  You can then open the *.csv with Excel and save.

For example, with SonarQube server running locally, I use this URL to extract all unresolved issues with the tag "leak":

http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?resolved=false&tags=leak